# Помогите, javascript

Tags: javascript

столкнулся с проблемой. В чем ошибка? Нужно сделать игру угадай число. Которая бы шла до победного или один из игроков не сдался. Столкнулся с проблемой когда игроку нужно сдаться. Выдает ошибку в брейке, но гуглю и синтаксис вроде похожий. В общем вот код, заранее спасибо!

```
var answer = parseInt(Math.random() * 100);
var end = 0

do { var user1Answer = +prompt("Player 1, Угадай число от 1 до 100");
     var user2Answer = +prompt("Player 2, Угадай число от 1 до 100");}
while  ( (answer != user1Answer) || (answer != user2Answer) || (user1Answer != user2Answer))
 {
    if (user1Answer = end || user2Answer = end) 
        break;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
do {
  var user1Answer = +prompt("Player 1, Угадай число от 1 до 100");
  var user2Answer = +prompt("Player 2, Угадай число от 1 до 100");
  if (user1Answer == end || user2Answer == end) 
    break;
} while ( (answer != user1Answer) || (answer != user2Answer) || (user1Answer != user2Answer))
```

Answer (score -1):

Проблема твоей проверки if в том, что она находится вне цикла, отсюда и ошибка

Вот исправленный и обновленный код:

```js
const answer = parseInt(Math.random() * 100);
const end = 0;

while((answer != user1Answer) || (answer != user2Answer) || (user1Answer != user2Answer)){
    const user1Answer = +prompt("Player 1, Угадай число от 1 до 100");
    const user2Answer = +prompt("Player 2, Угадай число от 1 до 100");
    if(user1Answer = end || user2Answer = end){break;}
}
```

Советую почитать про `let var const`, спойлер: способ `var` - устарел